# The Periodic Schrödinger Group 

Tags: laplacian

I've been working on Bourgain's paper 'Moment inequalities for trigonometric polynomials with spectrum in curved hypersurfaces' for my Master's thesis and everything was going great until I reached the last section where he begins with applications on the Laplacian; and introduces $e^{it\Delta} $,  the periodic Schrödinger group ...

I realize this might not be the best place to ask this; and I tried searching Bourgain's earlier papers for a definition to no avail, so would someone please tell me what $e^{it\Delta} $ is?

Comment: I would imagine it's operator notation. $e^x = 1 + x + x^2/2 + \cdots $ so $e^{it\nabla} = 1 + it \nabla - t^2/2 \nabla^2 + \cdots $ 

Comment: Whoops, that should have been $\Delta$ rather than $\nabla$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I figured I should write it that way, but I guess the name caught me a bit off guard... 

Comment: Probabilistically the exponent of a Laplacian (=the Markov
geberator of the Brownian motion) is just the Markov transition operator. You may think of this as of a transition matrix.

Of course, for that you need to take $\Delta$ the negative definite (I.e. possibly change the sign)

Comment: This is an instance of Stone's theorem

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone's_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups


Answer (score 4, accepted):

$e^{it\Delta}$ is the Fourier multiplier $e^{-4it\pi^2\vert D\vert^2}$, i.e. the operator defined by
$$
(e^{it\Delta} u)(x)=\int_{\mathbb R ^d} e^{2i\pi x \xi}e^{-4it\pi^2\vert \xi\vert^2}\hat u(\xi) d\xi.
$$
It is also the convolution with  $E(t)$, say for $t>0$,
$$
E(t)(x)=e^{-i(d-2)\pi/4}(4\pi t)^{-d/2}e^{i\vert x\vert^2 /(4t)},\quad
(e^{it\Delta} u)(x)=(E(t)\ast u)(x).
$$
The Fourier multiplier definition is the simplest.

Comment: Thanks Bazin!
The Fourier multiplier definition is EXACTLY what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Heuristically it is what Ryan Budney suggests, but of course it does not make sense as a power series, only for so called analytic vectors (which are dense though in this case).

Usually you define this via the spectral theory of selfadjoint operators, see for example

Weidmann: [Linear operators in Hilbert space](http://books.google.de/books/about/Linear_operators_in_Hilbert_spaces.html?hl=de&id=_SDvAAAAMAAJ), Section 7.6.

The construction to show that the spectral theorem in this case reduces to the operator being a Fourier multiplier is described in Chapter 10.

Comment: Well, the Fourier multiplier is in this case just an other name for the spectral theorem.